# How to use hasNext() function in java

Tags: java, function, token

I'm a noob in Java taking basic steps. I found document in CoreJava textbook and in this online website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm
The author mentions something about token, which I cannot understand. Also, I still find it vague to figure out the main effect of this function.
Below is the code from the website:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;    
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ScannerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6";

      // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

      // check if the scanner has a token
      System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext());

      // print the rest of the string
      System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

      // check if the scanner has a token after printing the line
      System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext());

      // close the scanner
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

I don't understand why is it different from the first line of

`System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext());`

and the second, but the results are different(true to false). ??

Comment: `nextLine` consumed the `next` that it _had_.

Comment: I understand the use of nextLine, but havent got how to use hasNext() and its function.

Comment: step 1: stop using tutorialspoint. look for sources written by people who don't make mistakes against the basics of the language.

Comment: @Stultuske +1 tutorialspoint for the most part confuses the matter

Comment: both line does the same. checks if there is any line to consume. Its just *before consuming the line* and *after consuming the line*.

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for your advice. But as I am a beginner in Java programming, I never find any error code in TutorialsPoint. Always updated with new and simple examples. Nonetheless, I found mistakes on even well-known Java book as Core Java.

Comment: @NguyenDung that's the point. JavaTPoint and TutorialsPoint seem like they are reliable, but they are written (and maintained) by people who don 't really know the basics all that well (let alone the more advanced material). Books are (before release) proof-read and corrected (sure, errors can be missed) and later on, lists with errata can be found online. As for tutorialspoint, they create a text/video, and post it online. Example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_essential_training/java_final_modifier.asp "Value once assigned to Final Variable cannot be changed". this is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner`will process the input. In that case is checking wiht `hasNext` that there is something in the input String to read. As you don't processed anything it answers true.
Once you consume the input with `nextLine()` there isn't any content ready to process for your Scanner consumer. **Then, the `hasNext()` answers false.**

Answer (score 0):

`hasNext()` function tells: You have a token (in your case, you have a string).

When you invoke the first time `hasNext()` it returns true (because you have the string s linked in your `scanner` object).

When you use `nextLine`, you represent your string s in the output so the scanner object have no more other tokens (string) so at the second invoke `hasNext()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

A *token* is just the scanner input split up using a delimiter pattern (default is whitespace I believe).

You get `true` as the output the first time, as there is an input (i.e. `hasNext()` is doing what it says on the tin, it *has input*)

Then you print the line with `nextLine()`

When you try call the `hasNext()` again, it is false, as basically you've already used a line of text in your print statement (in your case there is only one), so there is no more input, therefore `hasNext()` is false.

From the docs:

`hasNext()`

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

`hasNextLine()`

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.